# Iterate through fields using array Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

I have this model:

```
class Some_model(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

and this function:

```
# create a function to upload a model object given a json object
def upload_object_values(model, json_values, keys=None):
    if json_values:

        # assign a value to each key which is a the field in the given model
        for key, value in json_values.items():
            setattr(model, key, value)
        
        # if the object has keys to check
        if keys:
            # check if exists using the keys
```

when called like this:

```
upload_object_values(Some_model(), {'field_1': 'val', 'field_2': 'val_2'}, ['field_2'])
```

It would do a get or create inside the `upload_object_values` function using the fields inside the keys parameter (e.g.: `field_2` as the parameter).

```
Some_model.objects.get_or_create(field_2='val_2')
```

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to mimic [**`.update_or_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create). You can do this with:

```
def upload_object_values(model, json_values, keys=None):
    model._base_manager.update_or_create(
        **{key: json_values[key] for key in keys},
        defaults={key: value for key, value in json_values.items() if key not in keys}
    )
```

You should here work with a reference to the model *class*, so not a model *object*:

```
upload_object_values(Some_model, {'field_1': 'val', 'field_2': 'val_2'}, ['field_2'])
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Some_model`</s> to `SomeModel`.

Comment: Also doesn't require model to be the suffix sir.